# Custom Java annotation - no matching ElementType

Tags: java, annotations

I want to create a custom annocation type, which I could use on:

local variable:

`@A
int i = 1;`

operation:

`@A
x = a + b;`

method call:

`@A
someMethod(int a, int b);`

There is an ElementType for the first one, but I can't see any option for 2nd and 3rd. Is there really no way (and no workaround) to have an annotation above anything I want? RetentionPolicy is SOURCE, so it's dropped at compile time. It's only to decorate the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put annotations on statements.

See also [Enum ElementType](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html) in the Java documentation.